# iphone passing value to label

Tags: iphone, uilabel, nslog

I'm implementing a [calendar](http://blog.webscale.co.in/?p=244) as part of my app, it shows the selected date in nslog, but I need to send this value to a label,
it show the value as 2011-02-08 in nslog

I created a label in ib,(and connect to it) 
 in *ViewController.h

```
    IBOutlet UILabel *dateis;
```

in *ViewController.m

```
 - (void)calendarView:(KLCalendarView *)calendarView tappedTile:(KLTile *)aTile{
NSLog(@"Date Selected is %@",[aTile date]);

[aTile flash];

dateis = [aTile date];
```

}

but I get the warning>

```
Incompatible Objective-C types assigning 'struct KLDate *', expected 'struct UILabel *'
```

EDIT, if I use

```
    dateis.text = [aTile date];
```

I get the warning

```
 incompatible Objective-C types 'struct KLDate *', expected 'struct NSString *' when passing argument 1 of 'setText:' from distinct Objective-C type
```

KLDate is the way the date was defined in the calendar,

- so how can I pass this value to the label (working on nslog, view code call in *.m)

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Try `dateis.text = [[aTile date] description];`

Comment: Thanks Bjorn, that was the answer!, so my I ended up solving it, making it a string (please see answer below), what would be the preferred way??

Comment: Both solutions do essentially the same. Pick the one you like more. The `description` message is sent to the date anyway (if you log it or create an own string, for example), so my solution creates a little less overhead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just assign a "Date" to a "Label"...

You are obviously using Appcelerator framework. (`KLDate` type)

So what you are looking for is :

```
 dateis.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aTile.date];
```

`stringWithFormat:` will in fact invoke `description`method of `KLDate`, so you can also use the equivalent :

```
 dateis.text = aTile.date.description;
```

To find this look at KLDate.h and check wich method returns a `NSString *` that you can assign to the good property of UILabel (look its documentation) which is `text`

You should check `description` method implementation if you need to write your own code to format the date...

Comment: hi good, your answer is both things that work thanks, Im not using Appcelerator (that I know at least), im gonna check it, looks very interesting

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
dateis.text = [aTile date];
```

Comment: hi, thanks, I tried it but got a warning as well, please find it in edited post

Answer (score 1):

Well, NSLog can take a lot of different class types as input and it figures out what it can display.  What is a KLTile?  How are you assigning the date to the KLTile, i.e. from what data structure to what data structure.  Somewhere there's gotta be a NSString or a formatted NSDate.  Maybe you can see the internal structure of a KLTile in the debugger.

Answer (score 1):

ok, so I dont know if is the proper thing to do, but its working!!
(please enlighten me to know if is fine!)

I just figured that if label wanted a string, then I will give it a string, haha, so,

```
     - (void)calendarView:(KLCalendarView *)calendarView tappedTile:(KLTile *)aTile{
NSLog(@"Date Selected is %@",[aTile date]);

[aTile flash];
NSString *str =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [aTile date]];
dateis.text = str;
}
```